# How to send emails with names in headers from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I need to send nice-looking emails from Python with address headers that contain names - somehow something that never pops up in tutorials.

I'm using email.mime.text.MIMEText() to create the email, but setting `msg['To'] = 'á <x@y.cz>'` rather than utf8-encoding only the name part, will utf8-encode the whole header value, which of course fails miserably. How to do this correctly?

I have found a sort-of solution [Python email module: form header "From" with some unicode name + email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551933/python-email-module-form-header-from-with-some-unicode-name-email) but it feels hard to accept such a hack, since there does seem to be some support for handling this automatically in Python's email package in email.headerregistry which should be used automatically as far as I can see, but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the right policy from `email.policy` to get the correct behaviour.

### Wrong Policy

[`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) will use `email.policy.Compat32` by default. That one was designed for backward-compatibility wih older Python versions and does the wrong thing:

```
>>> msg = email.message.Message(policy=email.policy.Compat32())
>>> msg['To'] = 'ššššš <ssss@example.com>'
>>> msg.as_bytes()
b'To: =?utf-8?b?xaHFocWhxaHFoSA8c3Nzc0BleGFtcGxlLmNvbT4=?=\n\n'
```

### Correct Policy

[`email.policy.EmailPolicy`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.EmailPolicy) will do what you want:

```
>>> msg = email.message.Message(policy=email.policy.EmailPolicy())
>>> msg['To'] = 'ššššš <ssss@example.com>'
>>> msg.as_bytes()
b'To: =?utf-8?b?xaHFocWhxaHFoQ==?= <ssss@example.com>\n\n'
```

### Python 2.7

With older Python versions (eg 2.7), you have to use the "hack" as you called it:

```
>>> msg = email.message.Message()
>>> msg['To'] = email.header.Header(u'ššššš').encode() + ' <ssss@example.com>'
>>> msg.as_string()
'To: =?utf-8?b?xaHFocWhxaHFoQ==?= <ssss@example.com>\n\n'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For anyone else using MIMEText, which doesn't allow passing this in constructor, just set `msg.policy = EmailPolicy()` afterwards.

Comment: @PetrBaudis: this is now fixed in 3.6