# How do I change the from line on a mail sent using smtplib?

Tags: python, smtplib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specify a sender when sending mail with Python (smtplib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540976/specify-a-sender-when-sending-mail-with-python-smtplib)

I'm using smtplib to send a mail in python.  When I view a sent mail, the from line only says "contact" because I have FROM = "contact@foo.com".  However, I'd like the from line to read "foo" instead (but still have an email recipient reply to contact@foo.com).  Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
FROM = "Foo <contact@foo.com>"
```