# smtplib can't send mail: 550 5.7.1 This system is configured to reject spoofed sender addresses

Tags: python-2.7, email

I got an error mail message :

```
User_One@mycompany.com
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. 
It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail     
from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

smtp; 550 5.7.1 This system is configured to reject spoofed sender addresses> #SMTP#
Original message headers:
Return-Path: <User_One@mycompany.com>
Received: from  localhost.localdomain (unknown [192.X.X.X]) (using
 TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))  (No client
 certificate requested) by smtpcompany.tw (Postfix) with ESMTPS id CB8752E03B7  for
 <User_One@mycompany.com>; Fri,  2 Oct 2015 14:24:41 +0800 (CST)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1672092220=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: <User_One@mycompany.com>
To: <User_One@mycompany.com>
Subject: We got something
```

I stuck with this for a while
I don't know where ia wrong
I try `smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)` works well
But company smtp fail
I think this line is weild :

```
 Received: from  localhost.localdomain (unknown [192.X.X.X])
```

Do you have any ideas?
Please help me   Thank you

Here is code :

```
def send_email(mail_from,mail_to,subject, body):
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    fromaddr = mail_from
    toaddr = mail_to if type(mail_to) is list else [mail_to]
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(toaddr)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = body
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.stmpcompany.tw', 25)      
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.starttls()
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried talking to the postadmin yet?

Comment: postadmin think it's code problem.Should I install something in my computer??

Comment: is there anything before 'Original message headers' part in error mail message?

Comment: (it will be very difficult to help if you keep changing important information in your logs, even after obfuscating them). Anyway: is gmail final destinaton for @mycompany.com emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sender address (from field in the email) must be a existing email address on the mailsever you use (mail.stmpcompany.tw).

The error message

> 5.7.1 This system is configured to reject spoofed sender addresses

occurs when you use an email address in the from field that either does not belong to a domain which the mailserver is configured for or the server also requries that a user with that emailaddress actually exists.

Your test with gmail worked because googles mailserver doesn't check whether the senders address is valid or not.

Comment: I think You are right.I really use ````from@mysite.com````  from ````http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540976/specify-a-sender-when-sending-mail-with-python-smtplib?rq=1````    And It works !!!  it's weird to use ````from@mysite.com```` sounds  like a fake sender.But it really works.